# Chrome returns unathorized(401) but Firefox returns 200

Tags: nginx, proxy, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

I have a server running behind a nginx proxy with SSL on. Testing the Admin front page gives different results on Firefox browser vs Chrome/Chromium browser.

- On Firefox is working fine
- On Chrome calls are giving 401.

I found particular interesting that running this command on the server access logs
`grep auth /var/log/medusa/access.medusa.log | awk '$6=="\"GET" && ($9=="401" || $9=="200") {print $9 " " $14 " " $15 " " $16}'` 
gives:

```
401 Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36
200 Ubuntu; Linux x86_64;
401 Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36
200 Ubuntu; Linux x86_64;
401 Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36
200 Ubuntu; Linux x86_64;
401 Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36
401 Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36
401 Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36
401 Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36
200 Ubuntu; Linux x86_64;
401 Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36
401 Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36
...
```

Nginx configuration file essentially looks like this:

```
        server {
                listen 443 http2 ssl;
                server_name ***;

                ssl_certificate /root/.acme.sh/***.cer;
                ssl_certificate_key /root/.acme.sh/***.key;

                location ~ {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
                }
        }
```

Obs: I removed some of the options in the above "server" configuration just to compare differences. With this minimal configuration, is still working fine on Firefox.

*Obviously, the question is how to get it working on all browsers. Thanks*

Comment: The difference between 401 and 200 is not generated by the config you show.  The 401 comes likely from the internal application on port 9000, but nothing is known about this.

Comment: Besides the fact that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, as a nitpick, it is not browsers returning HTTP error codes. They are just displaying whatever the **server** gave to them.